# Sublime Text can't find interpreters for SublimeREPL

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, python, sublime-text-3

Interestingly, I'm able to execute .py files through any of the `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python ->`* options, except virtualenv, which does nothing, or execnet, which is not applicable, but when I try any of the `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL ->`* options, it fails (silently), and when I try the `Ctrl`+`,`,`f` shortcut, I'm told "Cannot find REPL for 'python'". Python is in my path and I can run it from command prompt. What should I look at to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a REPL open and running before you can use any of the `Eval in REPL` or `Transfer to REPL` options, either by menu or shortcut. Once you have one running, you can then interact with it in those ways. In this case, obviously, you would want to have a Python REPL open, but the same rule applies for any language with a REPL.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Minor follow-up, but Sublime doesn't have syntax highlighting for Racket (only for Lisp), so when I try to send a .rkt file to REPL, it looks for the Lisp REPL (because that's what's doing the syntax highlighting). Is there a way to tell it to use the Racket repl?

Comment: @MattG - well, there's the [`Racket`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Racket) package from Package Control that adds a `source.racket` scope to your `.rkt` files - perhaps that might work?

Answer (score 1):

As MattDMo has stated in his answer you need to have a REPL running beforehand.

For those who are new to sublimeREPL and don't know how to launch the REPL and have not [read the documentation](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

This worked for me in Sublime Text 3:

1. Run command palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Tools > Command Palette...)
2. Type `repl`.
3. All pre-configured REPLs will show up. Choose the REPL for the language you are working on and press enter.

Alternatively you can also run a REPL using the `Tools > SublimeREPL` menu.